# filter NSDictionary from array of dictionary for a given key value pair

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, nsarray, nsdictionary, nspredicate

```
dataProvider_array = @[
                  @{
                      @"shop_id": @"4",
                      @"shop_name": @"Test shop 1”,
                      @"orders": @[
                                 @{
                                     @"order_id": @"288",
                                     @"user_name": @"User 1",
                                     @"order_type": @“special”,
                                 },
                                 @{
                                     @"order_id": @"289",
                                     @"user_name": @"User 1",
                                     @"order_type": @"special",
                                 },
                                 @{
                                     @"order_id": @"285",
                                     @"user_name": @"User 1”,
                                     @"order_type": @"normal",
                                 },
                                 @{
                                     @"order_id": @"286”,
                                     @"user_name": @"User 1”,
                                     @"order_type": @"normal",
                                 },
                                 @{
                                     @"order_id": @"287”,
                                     @"user_name": @"User 1”,
                                     @"order_type": @"normal",
                                 },
                                 @{
                                    @"order_id": @"284”,
                                     @"user_name": @"User 1”,
                                     @"order_type": @"normal",
                                 }
                                 ]
                  },
                  @{
                      @"shop_id": @"1",
                      @"shop_name": @"Test Shop 2”,
                      @"orders": @[
                                @{
                                    @"order_id": @"288",
                                   @"user_name": @"User 1",
                                 @"order_type": @"special",
                             },
                                 @{
                                     @"order_id": @"289",
                                     @"user_name": @"User 1",
                                     @"order_type": @"special",
                                 },
                                 @{
                                     @"order_id": @"290”,
                                     @"user_name": @"User 1”,
                                     @"order_type": @"normal",
                                 }
                                 ]
                  }
                  ];
```

This data is presented in grouped table view with option to select the orders.
We have 2 types of shop normal and special. So when any order of special type is selected by the user then all orders with same order id must be selected by user.

For example suppose user selected order_id 289 for second shop (id = 1) then user must select the same order id 289  for other shop also. How I can maintain this thing?

Comment: What do you mean by "How I can maintain this thing?" It is not clear what you want to do here, you should give us example of the data structure you are looking for when user selects order_id = 289, so then we can help you get to the desired result

Comment: when user select order_id = 289 for shop_id = 1 then i want to force user to select order with same order id (that is 289) for other shop (for which shop_id =4).

Comment: Get the orders of the other shop and filter order_id = 289.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to filter then you can use this solution but I'm not sure this is the best possible solution :-

```
NSString *orderID=@"289";//Replace this with your order id
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
NSArray *categories = [evaluatedObject objectForKey:@"order"];
NSPredicate *subPredicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(order_id == %@)",orderID];
   return [categories filteredArrayUsingPredicate:subPredicate].count;
}];
NSArray *filteredArray=[dataProvider_array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

> To test this I created my own data like :-

```
    NSArray *arr=@[@{@"order":@[@{@"order_id":@"1",
                                  @"order_name":@"a"
                                  },
                                @{@"order_id":@"2",
                                  @"order_name":@"b"
                                  }]},
                   @{@"order":@[@{@"order_id":@"3",
                                  @"order_name":@"a"
                                  },
                                @{@"order_id":@"4",
                                  @"order_name":@"b"
                                  }]},
                   @{@"order":@[@{@"order_id":@"5",
                                  @"order_name":@"a"
                                  },
                                @{@"order_id":@"6",
                                  @"order_name":@"b"
                                  }]}
                   ];
    NSString *orderID=@"1";
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
        NSArray *categories = [evaluatedObject objectForKey:@"order"];
        NSPredicate *subPredicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(order_id == %@)",orderID];
        return [categories filteredArrayUsingPredicate:subPredicate].count;
    }];
    NSArray *filteredArray=[arr filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Or as @Willeke suggested

```
filteredArray = [arr filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY order.order_id == %@",orderID]]
```

Comment: in the third line which key you are using to create categories array?

Comment: Yes. The result contains an order_id 2. It doesn't work with the data in the question. I don't want the copy-and-paste programmers to copy this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170770/discussion-between-dreambegin-and-willeke).